# Custom Memory Mapped Allocator SEGFAULTs on allocate after freeing

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault

So I needed a simple allocator to allocate (on occasion with zeroing) and later free 4K blocks from a pool of mapped memory. However, after implementing this, while testing I found that after freeing a block or two, if I tried to allocate a block, the program would `SEGFAULT`.

Curiously enough, when I free multiple blocks in a row, nothing seems to break.

**Some important definitions collected from other files:**

```
#define xmattr_constant __attribute__((const))
#define xmattr_malloc   __attribute__((malloc))
#define xmattr_pure __attribute__((pure))

#define xm_likely(x)    __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)
#define xm_unlikely(x)  __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)

#define ABLKLEN 4096    // 4K pagesize

typedef struct {
    uint8_t     magic[16];  // "sfDB5" "vX.XXXXXXX" '\0'
    uint8_t     *freelist;
    uint64_t    size;
    uint64_t    bounds;
} arenaheader;
```

**Allocation code:**

```
void *pd_arena;

void pd_init (size_t len, uint8_t *map) {
    int x;
    size_t const block = len / 256;         // arena physical size
    size_t const size = (block / ABLKLEN) * ABLKLEN;    // arena useable size
    arenaheader *header;

    for (x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
        header = (void *) &(map[x * block]);
        header->freelist = NULL;        // no free blocks because all are free
        header->size    = size;     // useable size
        header->bounds  = ABLKLEN;  // current bounds
    }

    return;
}

xmattr_malloc void *pd_mallocBK (void) {
    arenaheader *header = pd_arena;
    uint8_t *ptr;

    if (xm_unlikely (header->freelist)) {   // there's a sitting free block
        ptr = header->freelist; // return the free block
        void **next = ptr;
        header->freelist = *next;   // update the free list
    } else if (xm_likely (header->bounds < header->size)) { // no free blocks
        ptr = pd_arena;
        ptr += header->size;
        header->size += ABLKLEN;
    } else {    // no more blocks
        ptr = NULL;
    }

    return ptr;
}


xmattr_malloc void *pd_callocBK (void) {
    void *ptr = pd_mallocBK ();

    if (xm_likely (ptr))    // allocation was successful
        memset (ptr, 0, ABLKLEN);

    return ptr;
}

void pd_freeBK (void *ptr) {
    arenaheader *header = pd_arena;

    if (xm_likely (ptr)) {  // non-NULL ptr
        void *next = header->freelist;  // get current top of stack
        void **this = ptr;
        *this = next;   // move address of current top of stack to ptr
        header->freelist = ptr; // push ptr to stack
    }

    return;
}
```

**Test code:**

```
#define F_LEN   (1024 * 1024 * 1024)    // 1 GB
#define A_LEN   (F_LEN / 256)

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    int x, y;

    // setup
    int fd;
    uint8_t *map;
    assert (fd = open ("./pd_single.testout", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_EXCL));
    if (ftruncate (fd, F_LEN)) {
        perror ("ftruncate failed: ");
        return 1;
    }
    assert (map = mmap (NULL, F_LEN, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_FILE | MAP_SHARED, fd, 0));

    uint8_t *arena[256];
    for (x = 0; x < 256; x++)
        arena[x] = map + (x * A_LEN);

    // test
    volatile int *var;
    void *list[512];
    int lcnt = 0;

    pd_init (F_LEN, map);

    // per arena test
    for (x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
        pd_arena = arena[x];
        // allocate and write a few times
        for (y = 0; y < 256; y++) {
            assert ((list[lcnt] = pd_mallocBK ()));
            var = list[lcnt];
            *var = (x + 1) * (y + 1);
        }
        // free some but not all
        for (y = 0; y < 64; y++)
            pd_freeBK (list[lcnt]);

        // now reallocate some and write some
        for (y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
            assert ((list[lcnt] = pd_mallocBK()));
            var = list[lcnt];
            *var = 16;
        }
    }

    // cleanup
    munmap (map, F_LEN);
    close (fd);

    return 0;
}
```

After running the program through `gdb`, I found that it `SEGFAULT`s within `pd_mallocBK()`; specifically, on this line:

```
header->freelist = *next;   // update the free list
```

However, I can't seem to understand what is wrong with that line and/or how to fix it.

So, two questions, really (in order of importance, most to least):

1. What is wrong with the selected line and how can I fix it?
2. Are there any other allocators to which I can simply assign a region of mapped memory to use instead of having to implement this?

Comment: Is ABLKLEN set to 4096?  Can't you show a `main()` program which makes a sequence of calls that triggers the fault?  Have you run with [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/)?  See how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler added the test program that I used and the definition for `ABLKLEN`.

Comment: Nearly compilable: I had to add 8 headers.  What are `A_LEN` and `F_LEN`?  And why do you think the line `void **next = ptr;` should compile?  It doesn't for me (GCC 4.9.1 on Mac OS X 10.9.5 with compiler options `gcc -g  -O3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror xma.c -o xma`, which is the default set of options I use for compiling).

Comment: Fixed the part about the `LEN`s; I used options `gcc -g xma.c -o xma` w/ GCC 4.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.1.

Comment: That isn't enough warnings to be safe!  :D  I will have to study what you think that assignment is up to, but the compiler thinks it is fishy, so it is the first thing to pay attention to.  Incidentally, to only have one warning (after I provided prototypes for the various functions you define) is not bad going.

Comment: Note that `assert(map = mmap(NULL, F_LEN, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_FILE | MAP_SHARED, fd, 0));` is a bad idea; if the code is compiled with `-DNDEBUG`, all of a sudden it fails because `mmap()` is never called.  Worse: `assert(fd = open("./pd_single.testout", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_EXCL));` will only fail if the program successfully opens the file and was launched with standard input, file descriptor 0, closed.  Do the assignments outside the `assert` and then assert that the result has an expected value.  Note that `mmap()` returns `MAP_FAILED` when it fails.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the test code is _quite literally_ **test code**. I wrote it for the sole purpose of testing the allocation subroutines.

Comment: OK, but remember that bad practices are bad in test code as well as real code.  And test code has a tendency to live a long time.  They are _not_, however, the immediate source of your trouble.  However, I have to make sure that the file open, for example, doesn't fail because of the file already existing, but your assertion won't spot that error.  So, I've had to fix that already, though I shall be removing O_EXCL shortly because I don't want to have to remove your file before running your program each time.

Comment: Is your code intended to deal with releasing the same memory block twice?  The test code saves values in `list[lcnt]` but never increments (or decrements) `lcnt`, so each assignment is recorded in the same variable, and most of the memory is leaked, but you keep trying to release the same memory block multiple times.  I certainly get a crash on the line you highlight, because the address it is trying to access is `0x00000010` (written as 32-bit, but actually on a 64-bit machine).  Basically, the free list doesn't contain valid pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works better than the original, but still crashes eventually when starting to work on the last arena.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define xmattr_malloc   __attribute__((malloc))

#define xm_likely(x)    __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)
#define xm_unlikely(x)  __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)

enum { ABLKLEN = 4096 };

void pd_freeBK(void *ptr);
xmattr_malloc void *pd_callocBK(void);
xmattr_malloc void *pd_mallocBK(void);
void pd_init(size_t len, uint8_t *map);

typedef struct {
    uint8_t     magic[16];  // "sfDB5" "vX.XXXXXXX" '\0'
    uint8_t     *freelist;
    uint64_t    size;
    uint64_t    bounds;
} arenaheader;

static void *pd_arena;

static void pd_dump_arena(FILE *fp, const char *tag, const arenaheader *arena)
{
    assert(arena != NULL);
    fprintf(fp, "Arena: 0x%.8" PRIXPTR " - %s\n", (uintptr_t)arena, tag);
    fprintf(fp, "Size: %.8" PRIu64 ", Bounds: %.8" PRIu64 ", Freelist: 0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n",
            arena->size, arena->bounds, (uintptr_t)arena->freelist);
}

void pd_init(size_t len, uint8_t *map)
{
    size_t const block = len / 256;                   // arena physical size
    size_t const size = (block / ABLKLEN) * ABLKLEN;  // arena useable size
    arenaheader *header;

    for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++)
    {
        header = (void *) &(map[x * block]);
        header->freelist = NULL;     // no free blocks because all are free
        header->size     = size;     // useable size
        header->bounds   = ABLKLEN;  // current bounds
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++)
    {
        char buffer[32];
        sprintf(buffer, "arena %.3d", x);
        pd_dump_arena(stdout, buffer, (arenaheader *)&map[x * block]);
    }
}

xmattr_malloc void *pd_mallocBK(void)
{
    arenaheader *header = pd_arena;
    void *ptr;

    if (xm_unlikely(header->freelist))      // there's a sitting free block
    {
        ptr = header->freelist; // return the free block
        void **next = ptr;
        header->freelist = *next;   // update the free list
    }
    else if (xm_likely(header->bounds < header->size))      // no free blocks
    {
        ptr = pd_arena;
        ptr = (uint8_t *)ptr + header->size;
        header->size += ABLKLEN;
    }
    else        // no more blocks
    {
        ptr = NULL;
    }

    return ptr;
}

xmattr_malloc void *pd_callocBK(void)
{
    void *ptr = pd_mallocBK();

    if (xm_likely(ptr))     // allocation was successful
        memset(ptr, 0, ABLKLEN);

    return ptr;
}

void pd_freeBK(void *ptr)
{
    arenaheader *header = pd_arena;

    if (xm_likely(ptr))     // non-NULL ptr
    {
        void *next = header->freelist;  // get current top of stack
        void **this = ptr;
        *this = next;   // move address of current top of stack to ptr
        header->freelist = ptr; // push ptr to stack
    }
}

enum { NUM_ARENAS = 256 };
#define F_LEN   (1024 * 1024 * 1024)    // 1 GB
#define A_LEN   (F_LEN / NUM_ARENAS)

int main(void)
{
    const char filename[] = "./pd_single.testout";
    // setup
    //int fd = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_EXCL, 0444);
    int fd = open(filename, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0600);
    assert(fd >= 0);
    if (ftruncate(fd, F_LEN))
    {
        unlink(filename);
        perror("ftruncate failed: ");
        return 1;
    }
    uint8_t *map = mmap(NULL, F_LEN, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_FILE | MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    assert(map != MAP_FAILED);

    uint8_t *arena[NUM_ARENAS];
    for (int x = 0; x < NUM_ARENAS; x++)
        arena[x] = map + (x * A_LEN);

    pd_init(F_LEN, map);

    // test
    void *list[512];

    // per arena test
    for (int x = 0; x < NUM_ARENAS; x++)
    {
        int lcnt = 0;
        pd_arena = arena[x];
        printf("Arena[%.3d] = 0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", x, (uintptr_t)pd_arena);
        // allocate and write a few times
        for (int y = 0; y < 256; y++)
        {
            assert((list[lcnt] = pd_mallocBK()));
            int *var = list[lcnt];
            *var = (x + 1) * (y + 1);
            printf("[%.3d] data 0x%.8" PRIXPTR " = %d\n", y, (uintptr_t)list[lcnt], *var);
            lcnt++;
        }

        // free some but not all
        lcnt = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < 64; y++)
        {
            printf("[%.3d] free 0x%.8" PRIXPTR " = %d\n", y, (uintptr_t)list[lcnt], *(int *)list[lcnt]);
            pd_freeBK(list[lcnt]);
            lcnt++;
        }

        // now reallocate some and write some
        lcnt = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++)
        {
            assert((list[lcnt] = pd_mallocBK()));
            int *var = list[lcnt];
            *var = 16;
            printf("[%.3d] data 0x%.8" PRIXPTR " = %d\n", y, (uintptr_t)list[lcnt], *var);
            lcnt++;
        }
    }

    // cleanup
    munmap(map, F_LEN);
    close(fd);
    unlink(filename);

    return 0;
}
```

I've not yet tracked down the residual bug.  Note the diagnostic printing (verbose) and the different handling of `lcnt` in `main()`.  You were busy freeing the same memory multiple times, but not detecting that in your `pd_freeBK()` code.  You were also leaking memory because you were not incrementing `lcnt` in `main()`.

Comment: I figured out why it still dies on the 256th block: I was adding the size of the arena to the pointer in `pd_mallocBK()` for some odd reason. Instead, I should have done `ptr += header->bounds;` and `header->bounds += ABLKLEN`.